# CSS Transition height when element appended to div

Tags: javascript, html, css

Hello I want to transition div's height smoothly when I append an element to it, but I cannot get it to work
I read this SO post
[smooth growing of div when appending children using transitions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55729477/smooth-growing-of-div-when-appending-children-using-transitions)

but it does not answer the question correctly as it is fading in the element opposed to transitioning the div's height that the elements are in

http://jsfiddle.net/nexq40oz/

```js
setInterval(function() {
    var li = document.createElement("li");
    li.innerHTML = "item";
    document.getElementById("list").appendChild(li);
}, 1000);
```

```css
#menu #list {
    max-height: 300px;
    transition: max-height 0.15s ease-out;
    background: #d5d5d5;
}
```

```html
<div id="menu">
    <ul id="list">
        <!-- Create a bunch, or not a bunch, of li's to see the timing. -->
        <li>item</li>
        <li>item</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add a class that `transition` the `max-height` of the `li` element and add with `requestAnimationFrame` to have an effect on the parent element,

```js
setInterval(function() {
    var li = document.createElement("li");
    li.innerHTML = "item";
    document.getElementById("list").appendChild(li);
    requestAnimationFrame(() => requestAnimationFrame(() => li.classList.add('expand')))

}, 1000);
```

```css
#menu #list {
    background: #d5d5d5;
}

#menu #list li {
  max-height: 0;
  transition: max-height 1s ease-out;
}

#menu #list li.expand {
  max-height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div id="menu">
    <ul id="list">
        <!-- Create a bunch, or not a bunch, of li's to see the timing. -->
        <li>item</li>
        <li>item</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to have the effect I want, this answer is similar to the other SO answer I linked in my original post. I don't want to animate the items, but rather height of the container that holds the items. Run Andrei Fedorov's code snippet to see what I mean.

Comment: I am on firefox, and it seems to work around 25% of the time. I added `setTimeout(() => {requestAnimationFrame(() => li.classList.add('expand'))}, 20)` and it seems to work more often.

Comment: @AlexMortez, Run inside two `requestAnimateFrame` callbacks and it will work 100%, this will guarantee to add the class after painting.

Comment: Running two works 100% of the time, can confirm. thanks for this!

Comment: @AlexMortez If you are confused why use two `requestAnimateFrame` I suggest you [watch this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cCOL7MC4Pl0), especially at `20:30`

Answer (score 1):

```js
const ul = document.getElementById('list');
const item = document.querySelector('#list > li');

setInterval(function() {
  let h = ul.offsetHeight;
  let h_item = item.offsetHeight;

  var li = document.createElement("li");
  li.innerHTML = "item";
  document.getElementById("list").appendChild(li);

  ul.style.maxHeight = 'calc(' + h + 'px + ' + h_item + 'px)';
}, 1000);
```

```css
#menu #list {
  overflow: hidden;
  max-height: 20px;
  transition: max-height 0.15s ease-out;
  background: #d5d5d5;
}

#list>li {
  height: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div id="menu">
  <a>hover me</a>
  <ul id="list">
    <!-- Create a bunch, or not a bunch, of li's to see the timing. -->
    <li>item</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Looks good, going to wait to see if there is any pure CSS solutions for a bit, if not will accept, thanks :D